# large area clickable in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

This seems like a very basic question so i am sure its been asked before but I cant find anything. Please point me in the right direction.

I am coming to android after using phonegap and I want to try and recreate some of the behaviour. In my phonegap app I have some large panels on top of one another. Each panel contains an image and some text. In phonegap I simply placed the anchor tags outside of the div and everything was clickable - this is allowed as of html5.

In android it seems I need to make the `TextView` clickable and then the image. Am I missing a much easier way to make a block of content clickable? I could do this in a `ListView` if helpful?

Comment: you could put a click listener on the parent `ViewGroup` that holds the text and the image I suppose. Not sure how well that would work however

Comment: [this][1] will help you [enter link description here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761244/can-i-assign-a-default-onclicklistener-for-an-android-activity/5761362#5761362
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761244/can-i-assign-a-default-onclicklistener-for-an-android-activity/5761362#5761362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:clickable="true"` for the parent layout that houses both the TextView and the ImageView.  Then set the OnClickListener to the parent layout, either in code or by adding something like `android:onClick="onLayoutClick"` to the layout xml.